# How can I use two dimensional dynamic array as a Function parameters?

Tags: delphi

hi
i Have a problem when I use a two dimensional dynamic array. I use this: 
procedure ListDeleted(FilesList: array of array of Integer);
Delphi give me compile error
How can I fix it?

Comment: if you have found an answer which worked for you, you should choose it as the accepted answer (by clicking on the tick mark next to it)

Answer (score 11):

Declare the array type first, then use it in the parameter list

```
type
  T2DIntArr = array of array of Integer;

...

ListDeleted(FilesList: T2DIntArr);
```

Comment: @micheal, if this is the answer which worked for you, you should choose it as the accepted answer (by clicking on the tick mark next to it).

Answer (score 2):

Define a custom type:

```
type
  TIntArray2 = array of array of Integer;
```

If you just read the parameter content in ListDeleted, use

```
 procedure ListDeleted(const FilesList: TIntArray2)
```

If the parameters are about to be modified internaly , use

```
 procedure ListDeleted(var FilesList: TIntArray2)
```

If the parameters are to be modified internally, but the modification should not be propagated to the caller, use

```
 procedure ListDeleted(FilesList: TIntArray2)
```

But notice that the last declaration (with no const nor var) will make a temporary copy of the array before calling ListDeleted, which is not a good idea for performance.